# Datatables script DOM

Tags: datatables

I'm using [datatables](https://datatables.net/) and I have created this javascript code

```
table = $('#examples').DataTable({
        "ajax": {
            type: "POST",
            url: "./../../" + "/back-end/switch-ajax-listening/switch-ajax-listening.php",
            dataType: "json",
            data:
                {
                    actionId: "page1GetAll"
                }

        },
        dom : "B<'row'<'col-sm-6'l><'col-sm-6'f>><'row'<'col-sm-12'tr>><'row'<'col-sm-5'i><'col-sm-7'<'#colvis'>p>>",
        "buttons": [

            {
                extend: 'colvis',
                postfixButtons: [ 'colvisRestore' ],
                container : '#colvis',
                columns: '0,1,2,3,4,5'
            }
        ],
        responsive: true,

        "columns": [
            { "data": "idSelectPacketName"},
            { "data": "idSelectCompany" },
            {"data":null,"defaultContent":"<button>View</button>"}

        ], 
    });
```

It works very well but I cannot be able to understand this part:

```
"B<'row'<'col-sm-6'l><'col-sm-6'f>><'row'<'col-sm-12'tr>><'row'<'col-sm-5'i><'col-sm-7'<'#colvis'>p>>"
```

I have not written this string I have copied from an example but I am not able to understand how it works. Or have you known a guide to understand very well this string?

Because my problem is that some times the button is not aligned with the table, have you some ideas in order to solve it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit flakey [as the author admits](https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom#Future-development) himself, for now, you need to put the Datatables keyletters in the correct places amongst the html tags. Something like:

```
 dom : "<'row'<'col-sm-6'lB><'col-sm-6'f>><'row'<'col-sm-12'tr>><'row'<'col-sm-5'i><'col-sm-7'<'#colvis'>p>>",
```

(placing the 'B' after the 'l')

You may also have to use CSS to obtain the desired layout.